# Design of Pico hardware divider

Tags: hardware, cpu, pi-pico

I recently found out that Pico has "8-cycle signed/unsigned divide/modulo circuit, per core" [1]. To my untrained embedded eye this seems very fast, does anyone know how they did it? What algorithm they use? What I find even more curious is that Pico does not have floating-point unit so they cannot share its mantissa divider and hence it must presumably be also quite small, gate-wise.

[1] https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__divider.html#details

Comment: The link provided says it's done in hardware. In general, if something is done "fast", or with few CPU cycles, it's done in hardware.

Comment: Very good by micro-controller standards. The pico is an ARM Cortex M0+, with some luck they might be accessible as verilog (https://www.arm.com/resources/free-arm-cortex-m-on-fpga).